# How to cast date to string in psycopg2?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm sure it has something to do with registering custom type cast as described [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-from-sql-to-python). However, I'm not sure how to do that.

What I want to do is something like this:
`SELECT * FROM table`
and where a column is of `date` type, I want psycopg2 to convert it to Python string instead of datetime.

Comment: Can't you just convert the `datetime` instance after retrieving it from the database‽

Comment: Nope, because Python 3.4.3 can't accept date like '-1-11-30'. It will throw `ValueError: year is out of range`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
def register_New_Date():
    # Cast PostgreSQL Date as Python string
    # Reference:
    # 1. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.new_type
    # 2. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-from-sql-to-python
    # 1082 is OID for DATE type.
    NewDate = psycopg2.extensions.new_type((1082,), 'DATE', psycopg2.STRING)
    psycopg2.extensions.register_type(NewDate)
```

Then run:

`register_New_Date()`

Comment: Rather than a hard-coded OID value, the `(1082,)` parameter can be substituted with `psycopg2.extensions.DATE.values`.